# How to log into running terminal/shell with ssh

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

so I am running a Minecraft server currently, and I'm logging into my server (Ubuntu Server, 16.04 on HP Proliant dl580 G5) through ssh. the only problem I've run into is that when my connection is lost and sign back into the server, the terminal output of the server is gone. I've tried using the screen application, but when I try to return to the screen with `screen -r`, it says that there are no running screens. I think that there is a way to see running processes and interact with them, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

Your screen session is probably still attached.

Try this:

```
screen -list
screen -d (with label, for more than one session)
screen -r
```

Btw: There are also some great alternatives like tmux